# How to change rgb image into matrix using EBImage?

Tags: r

I want to change an image into matrix of numbers in R using `EBImage` package. I have tried this code but it only output all 1's:

```
library(EBImage)
img<-readImage("test.jpg")
imageData(img)[1:50,1:60,1]
```

this is the image 
[image]

Comment: works like a charm on an rgb jpg here. could you share your .jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

The following example illustrates how to load a grayscale image containing an alpha channel, convert it to single-channel grayscale image, and do some post-processing: crop the border and resize.

```
library(EBImage)

img <- readImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VTWx.png")

# grayscale images containing an alpha channel are represented in EBImage as
# RGBA images by replicating the grayscale intensities over the red, green and
# blue channels

print(img, short=TRUE)
## Image 
##   colorMode    : Color 
##   storage.mode : double 
##   dim          : 819 460 4 
##   frames.total : 4 
##   frames.render: 1 

# convert to grayscale
img <- channel(img, "gray")

# collect matrix indices of non-white pixles
ind <- which(img < 1, arr.ind=TRUE)

# find min/max indices across rows/columns
ind <- apply(ind, 2L, range)
rownames(ind) <- c("min", "max")

ind
##     row col
## min  17   7
## max 819 413

# crop the image
img <- img[ind["min","row"]:ind["max","row"], ind["min","col"]:ind["max","col"]]

# resize to specific width and height
img <- resize(img, w=128, h=128)

display(img)
```

[image]

To extract the underlying matrix use `imageData(img)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's not a JPEG image, but PNG. 
Second, it's not RGB, but greyscale + alpha (according to ImageMagick at least), although the alpha channel is completely opaque, so it doesn't hold any actual data.
Third, the reason you're getting all ones is because the section of the image you are choosing is all white, i.e. maximum intensity, which is represented by the value 1.

Try something like `imageData(img)[51:100,1:60,1]` and see if that doesn't give a different result.

Comment: yes it give a different result. is there a way how to cut off the maximum intensity value in the edge of the image. and to resize image to fit to matrix of 20X20 in EBImage.